# sqlite variable and unknown number of entries in column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am sure this question has been asked before, but I'm so new to SQL, I can't even combine the correct search terms to find an answer! So, apologies if this is a repetition.

The db I'm creating has to be created at run-time, then the data is entered after creation. Some fields will have a varying number of entries, but the number is unknown at creation time.

I'm struggling to come up with a db design to handle this variation.

As an (anonymised) example, please see below:

```
| salad_name | salad_type | salad_ingredients          | salad_cost |
| apple      | fruity     | apple                      | cheap      |
| unlikely   | meaty      | sausages, chorizo          | expensive  |
| normal     | standard   | leaves, cucumber, tomatoes | mid        |
```

As you can see, the contents of "salad_ingredients" varies.

My thoughts were:

1. just enter a single, comma-separated string and separate at run-time. Seems hacky, and couldn't search by salad_ingredients!
2. have another table, for each salad, such as "apple_ingredients", which could have a varying number of rows for each ingredient. However, I can't do this, because I don't know the salad_name at creation time! :(
3. Have a separate salad_ingredients table, where each row is a salad_name, and there is an arbitrary number of ingredients fields, say 10, so you could have up to 10 ingredients. Again, seems slightly hacky, as I don't like to unused fields, and what happens if a super-complicated salad comes along?

Is there a solution that I've missed?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on my experience the best solution is based  on a normalized  set of tables

```
table salads

id
salad_name
salad_type
salad_cost
```

.

```
table ingredients 

id
name
```

and

```
table salad_ingredients
id
id_salad
id_ingredients
```

where id_salad is the corresponding if from salads
and id_ingredients is the corresponding if from ingredients

using proper join  you can get (select) and filter (where) all the values you need

Comment: Thanks very much, indeed!